# Web Mapping Services from Europe besides OSM

Tags: wms, data

Wondering if there are any other Web Mapping Services based in Europe or even Asia?
Fed up with the Bings and Googles and even OSMs of the WMS world. 
This is 2012 not 2002, shouldn't we have a much better FREE view of the world by now?

Comment: can you say what is wrong with the existing services? is it the data, the styling...?

Comment: lack of scalability, coverage issues with satellite coverage, holes in the data, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You mention lack of scaleability, coverage issues with satellite data and holes in data.

Satellite data (for the whole world) comes at a huge cost to acquire, and you want it for free?  Something has to give.  These are all issues not related to the map providers, they are satellite imagery provider specific.

You want free satellite imagery at good scale for the entire world?  So do I.  This data is acquired by the providers, then paid for through subscription and data sales.  Until someone finds a cost model that is different (ie Google acquires their own and pays via advertising, or governments pay for imagery is release it freely) this isn't going to change.

If you are more interested in the vector data obtained from satellite (or other means) and Google / Bing / OSM  are not your cup of tea, there are other ways to render the OSM data.  Some existing solutions are [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) which offers tiles based on both commercial and OSM data.  Another option is something like [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/), which have a number of pre built sets of tiles using OSM, along with products that allow you to build your own.  The beauty of OSM is that if you find holes in the data, you can fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**It's all about the data**:

Please NOTE: Both Bing and Google use DATA from the same providers Navteq owned by Nokia or TeleAtlas owned by TomTom.

If you want a different NON OSM mapping then
**http://www.viamichelin.com/**
has it with their own data in conjunction with [Europa Technologies Ltd](http://www.europa-tech.com/globalmaps.php)
 and viamichelin provides an API

[image]

Which has some of the best Routing/Directions for Europe (includes Turkey and other surrounding non-Euro countries)

via Michelin API [includes SOAP, REST, JavaScript v2]

http://dev.viamichelin.com/

http://dev.viamichelin.com/data/api-jsv2/iti1.htm

More Javascript Examples:
http://dev.viamichelin.com/web/api-javascript/examples-v2

Comment: I don't think Google uses NAVTEQ for much anymore; They moved towards TeleAtlas (and local providers) and recently have moved towards their own.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 'other' content, then try the [arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/) site and search for the places you are looking for. You may find some user shared web map that suits your requirement.

Comment: I wonder if arcgis.com will ever offer something like this: GeoEye Receives U.S. Government Contract Award for New Web Mapping Service            GeoEye's dissemination system provides users secure access to unclassified, high-resolution color imagery of an entire country over the Web.           http://www.gisuser.com/content/view/20273/132/